# Safari on Yosemite stops loading tabs if a new one is created

Tags: macos, safari, bug, web-browsing

If I visit a site in Safari, and **before** it loads, create a new tab or switch over to an existing one, the loading stops in the initial tab.

Has anyone else experienced this as well? None of the Yosemite updates has fixed this issue for me. I've reinstalled the entire OS as well but the problem still persists.

Comment: on what hardware with how much RAM, at what Internet speed?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Retina macbook pro and a Mac Pro. Both 16gb ram. Internet speed is over 50mbps.

Comment: OK, I tried few times, opening the new tab while the previous was loading, and it does not stop loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this bug. It is indeed a bug in Yosemite that hasn't been addressed till now. This fixes it:

1. Open Network Preferences
2. Go to Advanced
3. Go to TCP/IP tab
4. Change "Configure IPv6" to "Local-link only"
5. Restart the computer

Hopefully Apple will fix this annoyance in the near future. Until then, this solution works.

Comment: could you theorize as to why this changes the behavior? Do you know what the setting could otherwise change — EG I'm unfamiliar with how IPv6 is configured and what I'd expect in changing the method / applicability?

Comment: No clue at all as to WHY this worked -- all I know is that this solved the problem.

Comment: I still have this problem. You imply above this is a known bug -- do you have a link to support that claim?

Comment: Your solution still works, over 3 years after the original answer. Thanks for sharing; surprising there's such an non-intuitive connection between ipv6 settings and Safari tabs behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen every time with OS X 10.10.2 and below. It has somewhat lessened with the 10.10.3 update. But it does still happen. The only way I've found around it is to make sure some of the site loads on the tab before creating a new tab (or even switching to an existing tab).

Sorry, I was hoping to just post this as a comment, but not enough reputation yet.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one with this problem. I found a temporary fix until Apple fixes it at the core. Posted it as an answer.